# How to create folder in Google Drive using .NET API?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I am using C#, Google .NET API. How can I create a folder in Google Drive root location? Any code will be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

A folder can be treated as a file with a special MIME type: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder".

The following C# code should be what you need:

```
File body = new File();
body.Title = "document title";
body.Description = "document description";
body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

// service is an authorized Drive API service instance
File file = service.Files.Insert(body).Fetch();
```

For more details check the docs: https://developers.google.com/drive/folder

Comment: I am not able to create folder and no error is received too. Moreover .Fetch() method is not coming for me?
how to instantiate driveservice? i am using it like this

DriveService ds = new DriveService();
ds.Key = PicasaAuthToken;

thanks.

Comment: Please check the docs to learn how to perform authentication (https://developers.google.com/drive/apps_overview), a Picasa auth token doesn't help with Drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
//First you will need a DriveService:

ClientSecrets cs = new ClientSecrets();
cs.ClientId = yourClientId;
cs.ClientSecret = yourClientSecret;

credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        cs,
                        new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        null
                    ).Result;

DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "TheAppName"
                });

//then you can upload the file:

File body = new File();
body.Title = "document title";
body.Description = "document description";
body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

File folder = service.Files.Insert(body).Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Google Drive API, a folder is nothing but a file with Mime Type: `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`

In API v2, you can use:

```
    // DriveService _service: Valid, authenticated Drive service
    // string_ title: Title of the folder
    // string _description: Description of the folder
    // _parent: ID of the parent directory to which the folder should be created

public static File createDirectory(DriveService _service, string _title, string _description, string _parent)
{
    File NewDirectory = null;

    File body = new File();
    body.Title = _title;
    body.Description = _description;
    body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };
    try
    {
        FilesResource.InsertRequest request = _service.Files.Insert(body);
        NewDirectory = request.Execute();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error Occured");
    }
    return NewDirectory;
}
```

For creating folder at the root directory, you may pass `"root"` as the parent ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it complete and add a parent-ID:

```
    public static string Drive_FolderCreate(string ParentId, string FolderName) 
    {
        // create your credentials here with the scopes you want
        GoogleCredential Credential = ...
        DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = Credential, ApplicationName = "Aanmeldingen" });

        // Check if the folder already exists and return it's ID
        string MapID = Functies.Drive_FolderExists(ParentId, FolderName);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MapID)) return MapID;

        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File Folder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        Folder.Parents = new List<string>() { ParentId };
        Folder.Name = FolderName;
        Folder.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

        var request = service.Files.Create(Folder);
        request.Fields = "id";
        request.SupportsAllDrives = true;
        request.SupportsTeamDrives = true;
        try
        {
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File response = request.Execute();
            return response.Id;
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

I hope it does the trick for y'all.