# Create folder on Google Drive .NET

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use Google Drive SDK. I'm okay with authentication and getting instance of `DriveService`. But I want to add a simple folder on root, I've found this:

```
File body = new File();
body.Title = "document title";
body.Description = "document description";
body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

// service is an authorized Drive API service instance
File file = service.Files.Insert(body).Fetch();
```

But Google.Apis.Drive.v2.FilesResource.InsertRequest don't have Fetch method?

How can I use File object to insert it on root folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create folder in Google Drive using .NET API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715962/how-to-create-folder-in-google-drive-using-net-api)

Answer (score 3):

```
File file = service.Files.Insert(body).Execute();
```

Work perfectly !!!

i've just had an error in my class that implement IDataStore.