# How to upload only a folder to Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

tl;dr: Cannot upload empty folder to Google Drive. Google API is unclear, need assistance.

I'm trying to create a program which can upload empty folders to the Google Drive. I looked at the Google Drive API for working with folders and it wasn't clear, so if you guys can give a clearer answer it would be appreciated!

I tried just switching the source code from Google for uploading a file, i.e. 
body.mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"; and so on. The error I'm getting is UnauthorizedAccessException because you can't convert just a folder into an byteArray.

I don't have very much knowledge of C#, so I don't know how to get around this problem. If you could include code snippets too so that I can visualize where to put the code I would appreciate that too!

Code:

```
  Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File folder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        folder.Title = My Folder;
        folder.Description = desc.;
        folder.MimeType = applicationvnd.google-apps.folder;
       //Tried ^ that, didn't work

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(folder).Fetch();
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = service.Files.Insert(folder).Fetch();
        File file = service.Files.Insert(folder).Fetch();
       //Again, tried those but that didn't work either

        File body = new File();
        body.Title = "Document";
        body.Description = "A test folder";
        body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Folder");
        //I know this doesn't work but had to try anyways
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "application/vnd.google-apps.folder");
        request.Upload();

        File file = request.ResponseBody;
        Console.WriteLine(File id  + file.Id);
```

I think that's about most of what I've tried, each didn't work. there were others I've tried but I've since deleted the code and since it doesn't work there was no point in re-finding it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create folder in google drive using c# net api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715962/how-to-create-folder-in-google-drive-using-c-sharp-net-api)

Comment: @mason I've already tried the answer for that link, and as commented there, .Fetch() doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I SOLVED IT (by finding the answer on another question):

Instead of File file = service.Files.Insert(body).Fetch(); (lots of people said this doesn't work,), use File file = service.Files.Insert(body).**Execute**();
Upvote (or however this forum works) the answer here:
[Create folder on Google Drive .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336918/create-folder-on-google-drive-net)

Code:

```
File body = new File();
        body.Title = "document title";
        body.Description = "document description";
        body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";

        // service is an authorized Drive API service instance
        File file = service.Files.Insert(body).Execute();

        //File body = new File();
        //body.Title = "My document";
        //body.Description = "A test document";
        //body.MimeType = "text/plain";

        //byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
        //System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        //FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        //request.Upload();

        //File file = request.ResponseBody;
```

I put in everything I commented out because I find it helps to see what code is and isn't included for it to work. Everything in the source code before this (see quickstart C# on Google for reference) is exactly the same.

Hope this helps everybody else that has the same problem!